# LTspice simulation: unexpected behaviour of circuit

Tags: voltage, capacitor, ltspice

I am trying to build a JFET driven current source in a more complex circuit topology than shown here.

Unfortunately, the simulation is not giving me the results I would expect.

I could trace the "misbehaviour" of my circuit down to this simplified version of it.

I would like to control VGS of the JFET and therefore the current of R2 with VBat1. As you can see in the image, I can't get the desired voltage to the node G. Without the RC-Filter the circuit works fine.

The graph of V(g) is as expected: a linear increase from 2V to 10V. With the filter I get this graph:

[image: Simulation in LTSPice. Without the RC-Filter.]

For the capacitors I selected Würth X5R. The curve doesn't change if I use different types of capacitors.

[image: Selected Capacitor]

What am I doing wrong? What do I need to change to get the desired linear curve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have 2 V on the drain. As the gate gets above 2V + pn-diode-drop, that gate-drain (and gate-source) will become forward biased and since you are driving via 10 MΩ, it will clamp the voltage.

With 10 V on the drain, you might see more expected results; the source will follow about 2 V below the gate voltage.

For systems like this, 10 M & 10 pF is not a robust set of parameters -- try 10 k and 10 nF.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Cassio19 Don't forget that SPICE models almost never come (even) close to their real life counterparts, so it's up to you to verify them before any simulation. Also, if this answer does it for you, then be sure to select it (the green check mark beneath the up.down voting arrows). This will let other people know, in the future, that similar problems may have an answer here.